# How can I persist a list of object between application launches

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I need to persist a list of object between application launches per user basis; how can I do it?

The object is simple: 4 strings and one int.

Comment: Are they user-defined application settings?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, please be more specific

Comment: Yes they are application settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

One way is to use `BinaryFormatter` to save a list of serializable objects to a binary file. You can use the `SoapFormatter` if you want a readable / editable file.

#### Sample

Here a class that makes it possible to save a list of serializable objects.

```
[Serializable]
public class BinareObjectList<T> : List<T>
{
    public void LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", fileName);

        this.Clear();

        try
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            // IFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            List<T> list = (List<T>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            foreach (T o in list)
                this.Add(o);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        // IFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

#### More Information:

- [MSDN: BinaryFormatter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)
- [MSDN: SoapFormatter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx)

### Update

You said in a comment that you try to save application settings. Consider using Application Settings.

[MSDN: Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems that I can only use primitive types ,but I want to use variable length list of objects .

Comment: You can only use this if you object and every property is `Serializable`. You said that your class has only string and int properties. This will work.

Comment: Where can I find XmlFormater?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Its called SoapFormatter, wich is xml in soap format. My answer is updated.

Comment: I'll go with 'XmlSerializer' it seems that 'SoapFormatter' is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

[Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) the object to the users [appdata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) directory or use the [`IsolatedStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws.aspx) when you want to persist it and deserialize it when launching.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to just store them as user-scoped application settings

[image]

Then you can just access them via static properties

```
MyApplication.Properties.Settings.Default.StringOne = "herpaderp";
MyApplication.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws.aspx).

Comment: I never even knew about this. Now I have something new to read  up on.